# Написать программу вычисляющую 1/1!+1/2!+...1/k! 2мя способами. С применением рекурсии и без нее

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия, ряды, факториал

Неправильно работает часть с рекурсией. Никак не пойму, как исправить.
Мой код-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
double func(int);
double recfunc(int);

int main(){
    double k,sum,recsum;
    cout << "Enter k"<<endl;
    cin >> k;
    cout << "Function without rec=" << func(k) << endl;
    cout << "Function with rec=" << recfunc(k) << endl;
    return 0;
}

double func(int k)
{
    double n = 1;
    double sum = 0;
    if (k <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
    for (double i = 1.0; i <= k; i++) 
    {
        n *= i;
        sum +=1.0/n;
    }
    return sum;
 }
double recfunc(int k)
{
    double r=1.0;
    double recsum = 1.0;
    if (k <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        r *=(recfunc(k - 1) * k);
        recsum += 1/r;
    }
        return recsum;



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего -

```
double recfunc(unsigned int k)
{
    if (k == 1) return 1;
    double r = 1.0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= k; ++i) r/=i;
    return recfunc(k-1) + r;
}
```

Но подумайте, как оптимизировать, чтоб не считать каждый раз факториал с нуля :)

Answer (score 2):

Применение рекурсии во время компиляции:

```
template<size_t n>
struct Fact {
    enum { res = n * Fact<n - 1>::res };
};
template<>
struct Fact<0> {
    enum { res = 1 };
};
template <size_t n, size_t...args>
struct Fact_arr {
    static constexpr auto& array =
        Fact_arr<n - 1, Fact<n>::res, args...>::array;
};
template <size_t...args>
struct Fact_arr<0, args...> {
    static constexpr int array[] = { 1, args... };
};
```

А вот структура, рекурсивно создающая массив факториалов чисел

```
template <size_t n>
struct fact_array {
    static constexpr auto& array =
        Fact_arr<n>::array;
};
```

Теперь остается выполнить простой расчет суммы:

```
const size_t k = 10;
double sum = .0;
for (size_t i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {       
    sum += 1.0 / fact_array<k>::array[i];
}
std::cout << sum;
```